# $A^n$ space of functions that have $n-1-$derivatives absolutely continuous functions - Equivalent definition

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

I am studying the $A^n$ space of functions that have $n-1-$derivatives absolutely continuous functions.
By [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity),
[image]

> > So, $f\in A^n\iff (f\in C^{n-1}\text{ and } f^{(n)}\text{ integrable })$, am I right?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe worth being a bit pedantic: $f^{(n-1)}$ is continuous, but differentiable only almost everywhere, and $f^{(n)}$ is more than integrable: it satisfies
$$
f^{(n-1)}(x) = f(a) + \int_a^x f^{(n)}(t)~dt.
$$
Otherwise, you could run into the issue with the Cantor function, where $f^{(n-1)}$ is differentiable a.e. with derivative $0$, but not constant.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am afraid I could not understand very well. So, $f\in A^n\Longrightarrow (f\in C^{n-1}\text{ and } f^{(n)}\text{ integrable })$, but the reverse does not hold? About Cantor function, it is not almost everywhere differetiable, is it? Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, the converse does not hold: $f\in A^n$ implies something stronger than your conclusion. The Cantor function is an example of a nonconstant measurable function on $[0,1]$ which is differentiable almost everywhere, but has derivative zero wherever the derivative is defined. If you don't know of it, you should look it up - it is the most important example for understanding absolute continuity.

Comment: I relapsed but look it up now, thank you really much.